# How to Use Scrapy on Anaconda

Tags: python, web, scrapy, web-crawler, anaconda

i´m with some problems when i try to use Scrapy.
I am following the Scrapy Tutorial ([here](http://http:/https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html)) and i can´t create a project.

They asked me to use

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

to create a project and use Scrapy
([As this image shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7gLF.png))

I was using the Spider IDE (found in Anaconda Navigator) but the instructions doesn´t work there, even the code (and i was importing scrapy). So i go to the Anaconda Prompt and got the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\wid>scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 252, in __init__

    log_scrapy_info(self.settings)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", line 149, in log_sc
rapy_info
    for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 35, in sc
rapy_components_versions
    ("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 43, in _g
et_openssl_version
    import OpenSSL
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\bind
ing.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: O sistema operacional não pode executar %1.

(base) C:\Users\wid>
```

[Error on Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V26Y2.png)

When i activate my Environment i still got the same error.

PS: There was another topic about it here but there wasn´t any solution.

Comment: Put the error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: sorry, i already changed